# Google AdWords vouchers - can I use several of them?

Tags: google-ads, marketing, usage-data

I have a website for example `www.site.com`, I got also a Google AdWords account, and I got some vouchers from many of my friends around the world.

Now I'm wondering if I can use all these vouchers to promote my website in my AdWords champaign since they are some from USA and some from UK, and as far as I know they should be used in the country were you got them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google only allows an AdWords account to use one voucher. If you have multiple vouchers from different friends, use the most valuable one. [The only way to get around it appears to be to create multiple AdWords accounts and use one voucher per account](https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/how-to-use-multiple-adwords-coupons-successfully.2062898/). Doing so will not put you in the Google graces of Google and your accounts will be shut down if they catch you.

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally managed to use two vouchers on one AdWords account: while creating it I entered a voucher code, got an error message and entered another voucher code. After the first payment (which is a requirement for those vouchers), both voucher codes were added to my account.

However, I can't add new voucher codes to this account anymore. This trick only seemed to work while creating the account, and perhaps even that was a glitch from Google.